# Effecient Bulk Update of Model Records in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a Django app that will periodically take information from an external source, and use it to update model objects.

What I want to to be able to do is create a `QuerySet` which has all the objects which *might* match the final list. Then check which model objects need to be created, updated, and deleted. And then (ideally) perform the update in the fewest number of transactions. And without performing any unnecessary DB operations.

Using `create_or_update` gets me most of the way to what I want to do.

```
jobs = get_current_jobs(host, user)

for host, user, name, defaults in jobs:
    obj, _ = Job.upate_or_create(host=host, user=user, name=name, defaults=defaults)
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't delete anything that no longer exists.

I could just delete everything up front, or do something dumb like

```
to_delete = set(Job.objects.filter(host=host, user=user)) - set(current)
```

(Which is an option) but I feel like there must already be an elegant solution that doesn't require either deleting everything, or reading everything into memory.

Comment: What you can do is to add a "last modified" field to the model and set it to `now()` on every bulk update. You can then read the most lately modified instance before you do a bulk update (and store that value), do your update, then delete everything that is not updated (i.e. have a modified date earlier than the stored date).

Comment: Ha. I need to get some sleep. Thank you, kind stranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Redis](https://redis.io/) for storage and use [this](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) python package in your code. For example:

```
import redis
import requests

pool = redis.StrictRedis('localhost')
time_in_seconds = 3600 # the time period you want to keep your data
response = requests.get("url_to_ext_source")
pool.set("api_response", response.json(), ex=time_in_seconds)
```

Comment: Nice idea. You can't tell from my example, but when I said "periodically" what I meant was "triggered by a commit hook" so this isn't actually a solution for my problem. I do like the idea though.

Comment: maybe you can skip the `time_in_seconds` and every time the event is triggered, you can store the values from API all over again against same key. the previous data will be replaced by new ones.

Comment: Ended up going with a version of this. Had to have a Redis server running on the host machine for Celery anyway, so why not?